# Trying to get property of non-object I cant pass data on a productdetails view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an error on my code of Productdetails View

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

**web.php** file:

```
Route::delete('/Destroy/{id}','ProductsController@destroy');
Route::get('/Edit/{id}', 'ProductsController@edit');
Route::post('/Update/{id}','ProductsController@update');

Route::get('/listing',function(){

    $products = Product::all();
    return view('pages.productlisting',compact('products'));

});

Route::get('Product-details/{id}','ProductsController@ProductDetail');
```

**ProductDetail Function** On controller

```
public function ProductDetail($id)
{
   $products = Product::findOrFail($id);
   return View('pages.productdetails', compact('products',$products));
}
```

**view** file:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
  <h1>{{$product->name}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

And I have a problem in my view in data attributes

**Mydatabase attributes**

*name*,
*price*, 
*category*,
*description*,

*platform*.

I need to pass these data on product details view

Comment: my model does't have any function or relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this, you're getting a single collection.

```
$products = Product::findOrFail($id);
```

You don't need to pass it in `foreach loop`. Change in your view file as below. Remove foreach.

```
<h1>{{$products->name}}</h1>
```

If you use `get()` method you would get multiple objects where you can use `foreach`.
But for `find()` and `first()` methods return single object so no need for looping.

Comment: THANK YOU  i removed it and  changed the variable from $products to $product